# Call outside API from MySQL by scheduler

Tags: mysql, api

I'm using MySQL to manage my soccer data base. DB consist of: home team name, away team name, match date, match time, home team logo, away team logo. I want to call API from https://api-soccer.com by scheduler (once a day) from server, then get data from API and put it on my DB.How can I do this? may be there is another way to realize?

Comment: Don't use MySql for this, use your client program, optionally ran as a service, for that. Leave the DB the task of storing and querying data.

Comment: Alejandro Every API call have a price 0,005$, i want to economy by calling it once from server, and then client call data from db. If realize it by calling from client I think I will spend a lot of money, because every client can call api a lot of times

Comment: Number of calls don't depend on where you call it from (they have really no idea of that), but on how you structure your code around it, and if their API allows for a single call to return multiple results. Once again, database servers are horrible for that, while other programming languages have many features/libraries for it.

Comment: Yeah, the way is: write some code to achieve that. But please make sure that their API allows data to be copied to your own database